# How can gasUsed of a transaction be lower than the gas used by internal transactions?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, gas, bug, internal-transactions

Take this transaction for example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb8c2ee4dcc07352b535317304ca64ada5b03ab3c868a2281609cfd4ac4c619e9

It reports a gasUsed of 163215 when calling the contract.

On the other hand, the initial call in the [parity trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xb8c2ee4dcc07352b535317304ca64ada5b03ab3c868a2281609cfd4ac4c619e9&type=parity) reports a gasUsed of 0x4a6c5, which is 304837. The contract itself calls another contract, which uses around 250k of gas if called directly or by other contracts (which is correctly reported by parity trace).

Are there advanced techniques to call another contract without using gas/hiding the gas or why is the gasUsed by the transaction lower than the gas reported by parity trace? Or is this some kind of bug/exploit?